# Could not find method classpath() for arguments Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I did not add anything to the project
But I immediately encountered this problem in AndroidStudio V3.3.1

```
Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

Comment: Update your question with full `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle`

Comment: this message indicates that you have added the *classpath* dependency in the wrong place in your `build.gradle` files : you need to declare this dependency `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'` in the `buildscript { dependencies { } }` block in your root level  `build.gradle` file, and it seems you have added it into project's `dependencies { }` block instead.

Answer (score 3):

this message indicates that you have added the classpath dependency in the wrong place in your **build.gradle** files : you need to declare this dependency **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'** in the **buildscript { dependencies { } }** block in your root level **build.gradle** file, and it seems you have added it into project's **dependencies { }** block instead.   --M.Ricciuti--

Answer (score 0):

I remove the project from Android studio and again import
 fixed error